# Can not store HTML when sent to php/sql through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I'd like to store some div content when a button is pressed. I need/want to save the html tags as well in order to reuse.

When I replace the post variables by any type of string, it works flawlessly. I tried cleaning the html variable from line breaks but it didn't do it, tried also to shell the $HTML post in a `$var = <<<HTML HTML`, but this didn't work either.

Here is the javascript :

```
$("#save").click(function(){
var pageHTML = $("#page_wrap").html();
var name_page = "name";
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/saveModel.php",
  data: {   nHTML: pageHTML,
            page : name_page
        },
    success:function(data){
      var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      var new_div = responseData.message;
      $("#page_wrap > *").remove();
      $("#page_wrap").prepend(new_div);
      $('.editable').aloha();
    }
})
})
```

And here is the php :

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','name','pwd');  
mysql_select_db('db');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$id = $_POST['page'];
$HTMLpost = $_POST['nHTML'];

$insertSignup = mysql_query("UPDATE Table_name SET model_test='$HTMLpost' WHERE    identifiant='$id'");

if($insertSignup){ 
$status = "success";
$message = "OK";
}
else {
$status = "error";
$message = "NOT OK";
}

//return json response
$data = array(
    'status' => $status,
    'message' => $message
);

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: consider what happens if the value of $_POST['nHTML'] is: '# DELETE FROM Table_name WHERE 1;

Comment: what if it had something like `'; Drop table Table_name; --`, Try escaping the HTML.. use something like [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to escape it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to change the quotes to make it safe for entry into the database.

```
$HTMLpost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nHTML']);
$insertSignup = mysql_query("UPDATE Table_name SET model_test='$HTMLpost' WHERE    identifiant='$id'");
```

Longer answer: You should not be using the mysql_() functions as they are being depreciated. Check out prepared statements with PDO or mysqli instead - they will safely handle this for you (and they are not being depreciated).

Reading: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php or google for more - plenty of examples around. Best to learn now before you get stung when the mysql_() functions do get removed.

Comment: Thank you.. somehow i completely forgot i was french and that we were using loads of '... shame on me and brilliant answer.